# how to pass props to component if the given argument is in </> syntax?

Tags: reactjs

I am making a library for show/hide modals and it works as follows,

you make a wrapper around your code:

```
<ModalProvider>
   // all of your app code here
</ModalProvider>
```

then you can use the built-in use context `useModal()` hook to show and to hide the modal as follows:

```js
const ContactPage = () => {
  const { showModal } = useModal()
  return (
    <button
      onClick={() => showModal(<MyModal prop1="a" prop2="b" prop3="c" />)}
    >
      Show Modal!
    </button>
  )
}
```

Now the consumer of my library have passed the argument `<MyModal .../>` to my `showModal()` function, I want to pass the following extra props to his `MyModal` component, so he can use them inside his MyModal component code:

- onClose (only this one)

But I don't know how?

I have tried to read the component props and to set them in my `showModal` method as:

```js
const showModal = (modal) => {
   modal.props.onClose = () => console.log('modal closed!')
}
```

but react refused by yelling at me saying:
[image]

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: sorry the error message was wrong, I updated the error message

Comment: @S.Marx, it doesn't need to have

Comment: props is ***read only***. `modal.props.onClose = ...`, you are trying to add a property to a read only object.

Comment: @MadhanS, Okay I know that, what is the solution?